# Sed acting differently in vi than command line on the same server

Tags: string, sed, replace, redhat

I am looking for a filesystem name (or / in the first column), if there is a slash or that filesystem (doesn't matter which) I want to join the two lines by replacing without the cr.

it works fine in vi.

```
 :%s:\n\/fs_name:\/fs_name:g
```

using : as the delimiter for clarity

I need to be able to replicate this in a script every time I run the job. So doing it in vi every time is not a solution

in other words I want:
first line

```
/fs second line
```

to become

```
first line /fs second line
```

using bash 4.2.46 on redhat 7. sed 4.2.46(s) and vim 7.4

Comment: If you're doing `:%s...` in vim, you're not using `sed`.  Using `sed` is vim is done with something like `!!sed ...` or `:1,$!sed ...`

Answer (score 2):

*sed* across newlines is somewhat non-trivial. I hope I got your intention correctly (see below) in which case you're looking for something like this:

```
sed -e 'N;s#\n/#/#' input.txt
```

Which keeps appending lines to pattern space. Then just replaces all instances of `<newline>` follow by `/` by just a `/`. You can do this in place by using `-i` argument to *sed*.

---

I've had a little difficulty navigating the question as it is currently formatted, but my understanding is you're after this. For each:

```
part1
/something else
```

You'd like to get:

```
part1/something else
```

---

As [William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140750/william-pursell) pointed out in the comment to your question. using `s` in *vi* is not the same thing as calling *sed* even though they are historically related and trace there roots back to *ed*. Command mode of *vi* is like editing you file using *ex*. Which BTW. is something you could do in a script as you can feed it commands through command line. E.g. `echo -e '%s#t#X#g\nwq' | ex input.txt` would be the same as doing `:%s#t#X#g` and `:wq` after opening `input.txt` in *vi*.